# Copy file from asset folder to external android memory unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have some of my files in my assets folder to be copied to the android device. How do you do it?

I have tried several ways, like opening the files via debugging, it works in the PC. But when I have transferred it to the android device, it doesn't work or either copy it whatnot.

```
    public void OpenPDF(string filename) //this opens the file I have in my pc. Via debugging in Unity.
    {
        TextAsset pdfTem = Resources.Load("PDFs/" + filename, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename + ".pdf", pdfTem.bytes);

        Application.OpenURL(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename + ".pdf");

    }

    public void openPDFfromSD()
    {
        Application.OpenURL("/mnt/sdcard/openme.pdf"); //this doesn't open the PDF file I have in my sd card.
    }

    public void legitOpen(string nameOfFile) //this opens the file I have in my pc. Via debugging in Unity.
    {
        string realPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nameOfFile + ".pdf";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(realPath))
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PDFs/"))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PDFs/");
            }
            WWW reader = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/PDFs/" + realPath);
            while (!reader.isDone) { }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(realPath, reader.bytes);
        }
        Application.OpenURL(realPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't use string concatenation directly to build system paths.

Rather always use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separator (`/` or `\`) according to your target platform.

Also later in `new WWW` you have added both the leading `Application.streamingAssetsPath` and `Application.persistentDataPath` already in `realPath`.

```
public void OpenPDF(string filename)
{
    TextAsset pdfTem = Resources.Load("PDFs/" + filename, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;

    var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename + ".pdf";

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath), pdfTem.bytes);

    Application.OpenURL(filePath);

}

public void legitOpen(string nameOfFile)
{
    string realPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, nameOfFile + ".pdf");
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(realPath))
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "PDFs"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "PDFs"));
        }
        WWW reader = new WWW(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "PDFs", nameOfFile + ".pdf");
        while (!reader.isDone) { }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(realPath, reader.bytes);
    }
    Application.OpenURL(realPath);
}
```

---

Btw if you want to prevent your app from completely freezing until the loading is done I would recommend to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) like

```
public void legitOpen(string nameOfFile)
{
    StartCoroutine(legitOpenRoutine(nameOfFile));
}

private IEnumerator legitOpenRoutine(string nameOfFile)
{
    string realPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, nameOfFile + ".pdf");
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(realPath))
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "PDFs"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "PDFs"));
        }
        using (var reader = new UnityWebRequest.Get(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "PDFs", nameOfFile + ".pdf"))
        {
            yield return reader.SendWebRequest();

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                return;
            }                

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(realPath, reader.bytes);
        }
    }
    Application.OpenURL(realPath);
}
```

Or even completely use an async method using [`CopyToAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync)

```
public void legitOpen(string nameOfFile)
{
    legitOpenAsync(nameOfFile);
}

private async void legitOpenAsync(string nameOfFile)
{
    var realPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, nameOfFile + ".pdf");

    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "PDFs");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(realPath))
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pdfPath)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pdfPath);
        }

        using(var sourceFile = File.Open(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "PDFs", nameOfFile + ".pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        {
            using(var targetFile = File.Open(realPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            {
                await sourceFile.CopyToAsync(targetFile);
            }
        }
    }
   
    Application.OpenURL(realPath);
}
```

---

#### However

note that [`Application.OpenURL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html):

> **Android**: Due security changes in Android 7.0 ([More information](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#sharing-files.html)), `Application.OpenURL` can **no longer be used for opening local app files**, you need to use [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) which allows you to share files with other applications.

and

> **iOS**: `Application.OpenURL` **cannot be used for opening local files**.

Therefore this won't work at all

```
public void openPDFfromSD()
{
    Application.OpenURL("/mnt/sdcard/openme.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

One note, about the fileprovider, would it work the same way in c# unity?

Comment: What do you mean by `the same way`? Unity doesn't say much about it only what I posted above saying that you should use the `FileProvider` for local files. Files within the application folder hierachy should be no problem. Maybe [this](http://www.daniel4d.com/blog/sharing-image-unity-android/comment-page-10/) helps you to use the `FileProvider` from within your c# scripts but it looks quite complex and honestly I'm not an Android nor iOs expert ;)

Comment: It's fine. I'll read everything you sent me. I truly appreciate the effort. Thank you so much for this! :)